# Score Questionare for different age groups combined

Tags: clinical-trials

Lets say we have two questionares for two different age groups. One has 100 items the other 150 items, where we can answer each question with 0 - 2. Then we calculate the mean value of all answers given. So for the first questionare this is a value between 0 and 200 and for the second a value between 0 and 300.

How can I compare the scores? Can I normalize the scores somehow?

Comment: If the two scores are comparable depends on the structure of the questionnaires. You can apply a simple linear transformation (e.g. divide the first scores by 2 and the second by 3 to get a value in $[0,100]$) and then look at the sample distributions of the scores for the first questionnaire and for the second. Are the two distribution similar? If not, what are the differences between the two distributions? Did you expect these? How can you explain them?